# Некликабельное поле ввода

Tags: html, css, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить этот код или скажите что с ним конкретно не так. Почему то когда пытаюсь нажать в поле ввода не вижу курсора текстового и вообще не могу ничего в это поле вписать, как в принципе и кнопку button не могу нажать. В принципе если немного опустить вниз form то поле ввода начинает работать и можно вводить текст и нажимать кнопку но мне нужно что бы оба хэдэра были на одном уровне. Да я знаю что много divов в документе это плохо выглядит я работаю над тем чтобы количевство дивов ограничивать.

```css
.page {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family:  Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  line-height: 1.52;
  color: black;
}
.header-left {
  position: relative;
}
.header_picture > img{
  float: left;
  margin: -2.5em 0.25em 0 3em;
  z-index: -1;
}
.header-documentation {
  font-size: 2em;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0 5px 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.link {
  line-height: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link_color_orange{
  color: #fe5000!important;
}
.header-right{
  float: right;
  padding-top: -5px;
}
.header-search {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.search-text-input {
  padding: 5px;
  border-top:1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 15px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 390px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: auto;
}
.submit-button {
padding:5px;
background-color:orange;
color:white;
border-radius:10px;
height: 35px;
width: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Technical documentation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="page">
   <header class="page-header">
     <div class="header-left">
 <a class="header_picture" href="https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klepsydra" title="klepsydra"><img src="historical-klepsydra_318-10279.jpg" alt="Klepsydra" width="150" height="150"></a>
     <div class="header-documentation"> 
 <a class="link link_color_orange" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation">Documentation</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
    <form class="header-search" action="action_page.php">
      <input type="text" class="search-text-input" placeholder="Search through documentation..." name="search">
      <button class="submit-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форма с инпутом и кнопкой накрыта блоком `.header-left`.

```css
.page {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  line-height: 1.52;
  color: black;
}

.header-left {
  float: left;
}

.header_picture>img {
  float: left;
  margin: -2.5em 0.25em 0 3em;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-documentation {
  font-size: 2em;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0 5px 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.link {
  line-height: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link_color_orange {
  color: #fe5000!important;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

.header-search {
}

.search-text-input {
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 390px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: auto;
}

.submit-button {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header class="page-header">
  
    <div class="header-left">
      <a class="header_picture" href="https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klepsydra" title="klepsydra"><img src="historical-klepsydra_318-10279.jpg" alt="Klepsydra" width="150" height="150"></a>
      <div class="header-documentation">
        <a class="link link_color_orange" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation">Documentation</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="header-right">
      <form class="header-search" action="action_page.php">
        <input type="text" class="search-text-input" placeholder="Search through documentation..." name="search">
        <button class="submit-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли .header-left заканчивается перед .header-right а .header-right  накрывает блоком форму с инпутом.

Comment: @ErykTibijczyk Постарайтесь писать комментарии к ответам на Ваши вопросы более вежливо. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по инпуту и выберите "Inspect".

Comment: ничего не понимаю как .header-left может накрывать форму с инпутом если он заканчивается перед .header-right

Comment: @ErykTibijczyk Значит не заканчивается. Вы сделали вот это: *"Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по инпуту и выберите "Inspect"*?

Comment: Да и я вижу что он накрывает весь хедер но левый хедер заканчивается перед правым, так что исправлять нечего разве что удалить весь хедер и начинать с начала что бессмысленно, так как я не вижу проблемы, код начинается и заканчивается

Comment: @ErykTibijczyk "левый хедер заканчивается перед правым" - С чего вы взяли? Вы же видите, что это не так.

Comment: Чтобы закрыть блоковый див использую </div> и в документе все дивы закрыты

Comment: хорошо вы были правы, действительно блок закрывает весь хедер но вы можете подсказать как это исправить, я уже несколько раз переставлял дивы местами менял значения но все равно не помогает, код написан правильно если вы тоже открывали через инспект то вы видели что оба дивы закрыты

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена достаточно было поменять главный header на div а класс .header-left на .header_left.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от моего ответа.